# Troubleshooting MySQL with Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

- When I connect to MySQL using the workbench it works fine.
- When I connect to MySQL using Java it works fine.
- When I connect to MySQL using the Entity Framework designer (e.g. Update Models from Database) it works fine.

But when I run the project I get "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

The Entity Framework designer is using the same connection string as the application. What else could be the problem?

EDIT:

- When I connect to MySQL using Entity Framework in a console application it works fine.
- When I connect to MySQL using Entity Framework in a console application in debug mode it works fine.
- When I connect to MySQL using Entity Framework in a unit test project it works fine.
- When I connect to MySQL using Entity Framework in a unit test project in debug mode it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your debug mode and release mode configurations the same? IE is one running in x86 and the other in x64?

Comment: Yes, but that's not relevant. I left the configuration on "Debug" the whole time, the only difference is I pushed Ctrl-F5 instead of F5.

Comment: Just trying to isolate the variables here. Are you able to use the debugger to inspect the EFContext object and see that it's picking the same connection string at runtime? I'd also consider checking the mysql logs and see if you can see the attempts. (likely not, sounds like you can't even open a connection to the server). And the MySQL server is local, correct?